# Visual Studio - Form Draws Very Slow with 60 controls present

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

I have a form with about 60 numeric entry boxes that takes about 2 seconds to load when making the form active. Even in the development environment when viewing the design it takes this long to load. Is this just part of visual studio or is there a way I can speed up the draw time?

Thanks,
-Eli

Comment: Which operating system are you running VS.Net 2010 on / running the program on?  Is it a Winforms, WPF or another technology application that you've created?

Comment: are they added dynamically or are they set up in the designer?

Comment: Are you binding data to the view of the controls when the form is made active? While 60 controls is a lot to fit on a single form, this quantity is not a serious drawing bottleneck for most stock controls available in Winforms and WPF.

Answer (score 0):

For practical tips for boosting the performance of Windows Forms apps, you should check out Milena Salman's excellent [MSDN Mag article on this subject.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc163630.aspx)